How to fix script which requires EFI System Partition (ESP) to be disk0s1 in macOS?
I see a post which is 12 years old: How to fix broken EFI partition?
System: Macbook Pro 2019 with Intel & T2, upgraded to Sonoma.
Objective: Dual boot with T2Linux Fedora using https://t2linux.org/
Trouble: I accidentally deleted the EFI System Partition on MacOS. Now, I do have EFI for T2Linux (EFI NO NAME), but NOT with macOS. Now, with T2Linux Fedora, it requires first to update 'firmware.sh' in MacOS.
Deleted EFI in MacOS:
#:     TYPE      NAME       SIZE        IDENTIFIER
1:     EFI       EFI        314.6 MB    disk0s1

Current diskutil list: (1 TB partition: 400 GB for MacOS, and 600 GB for Linux):
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list                          

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

   #:     TYPE                    NAME              SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:     GUID_partition_scheme                     *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:     Apple_APFS              Container disk1   400.2 GB    disk0s1
   2:     EFI                     NO NAME           629.1 MB    disk0s2
   3:     Linux Filesystem                          1.1 GB      disk0s3
   4:     Linux Filesystem                          598.3 GB    disk0s4

Current GPT Partition:
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo gpt -r show disk0

start       size         index  contents
0           1                   PMBR
1           1                   Pri GPT header
2           4                   Pri GPT table
6           76800         
76806       97715079     1      GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
97791885    115         
97792000    153600       2      GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
97945600    262144       3      GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
98207744    146068480    4      GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
244276224   36         
244276260   4                   Sec GPT table
244276264   1                   Sec GPT header

Output of Attempt to Install firmware.sh on MacOS:
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % bash ~/Downloads/firmware.sh
Detected macOS
Mounting the EFI partition
Volume on disk0s1 failed to mount because it appears to be
an APFS Physical Store (or is the APFS Container already mounted?)
See "diskutil apfs list"

EDIT: I tried the following Steps: But again, NO EFI was created:
# diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
unmount of all voulmes on disk0 was successful 

# gpt remove -i 1 /dev/disk0
/dev/disk0s1 removed

# gpt add -b 76806 -i 1 -s 97715079 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0s1
/dev/disk0s1 added

# diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s1
Finished file system repair on disk0s1

# diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk0s1
voulmes() mounted successfully

EDIT: Other Details (Asked by @David Anderson):
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.4.1
BuildVersion:       23E224

me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.

I am NOT good in linux. So, can some one guide me in very simple steps, please?

Was your last edit done from macOS, macOS Recovery or macOS Internet Recovery? What was the output from the sw_vers and csrutil status commands, when booted at the point where you entered the gpt commands?

@David Anderson: Sir: The steps in the edit were done using MacOS Recovery. I edited the question once again to add outputs you asked for.

tom_kp: I changed the title to more closely match your answer. If you disagree with the change, you can edit your question and make you own change or do a rollback.  I deleted my answer, since it no longer applies to the new question. If you need my answer in the future, I should be able to undelete. Also, be sure to return later and accept your own answer.

SOLUTION:

Only one EFI partition is enough for installation of more than one OS on bare metal

Since the EFI in MacOS was accidentally removed, I had to change the script in firmware.sh, as follows, as advised at discord for T2Linux for Fedora:

Open up the script and change disk0s1 to disk0s2

Also change nvme0n1p1 to nvme0n1p2




And, the firmware for Wi-Fi & Bluetooth was updated for both MacOS Sonoma and T2Linux Fedora.

You should accept your answer so others will know a solution was found.
